# Use int or Integer

Tags: java, integer, int

In my code there are a lot of final values, like 10000. They never change, i do nothing with them, just sometimes checks like `if(number1 == number2)`.

Is it better to use `int` or `Integer` for such numbers?

Comment: Do you compare these constants to variables of type `int` or `Integer`? If you compare them to `int`, then you can use `int` as the type of your constants to save the unboxing overhead. If you compare them to `Integer` Objects, then first of all your example does not work since it `==` compares the references of two objects. Instead you have to use `equals()` to insure the values are being compared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, use `int`.

In a general case, if you're in the situation where you could feasibly use either the primitive value is almost always preferred:

- They're potentially more memory efficient
- You can always use == reliably, which isn't the case with the class `Integer` type - you'd have to use `.equals()` to ensure you were getting what you wanted. See [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching) for more details.

Memory requirements are a lot less of an issue these days, but the big gotcha is the second one, which can cause the potential for a lot of bugs if you're not aware of it (especially since there's cases where `==` will work as you expect, and others where it won't - it's not a "reliable" bug in that sense.)

Answer (score 5):

Since `Integer`s are objects, they take up more space in memory. If you don't ever use `Integer` methods or anything else requiring it to be an object, `int`s are more memory-efficient, since `int` is a primitive type.

In the grand scheme of things, it probably won't matter given how much memory modern computers have. No harm being safe though.

I should note that if you're using `==` for `Integer`s, you're checking if the references are the same. For `Integer` objects, the `equals()` method will be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

use int, as it is the primitive type. It is always a better option because of memory efficiency to choose a primitive type instead of choosing a full fledged wrapper object.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter if it's `int` or `Integer`. In java, they're very interchangeable by the use of [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

It does however make a difference if you plan to store them in a collection. Collections only accept objects, which means you'll have to use `Integer`.

If you decide to use `Integer` and want to compare them, don't use `==`. Instead, use the `compareTo` method or the `equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing references so its better to use int.
Never use "==" to compare Integer objects (or Float, Double, Short, Character, Byte, Long, BigDecimal...) for equality. Compare numbers in their primitive form -- i.e., work with int, short, long, double.

If you want to compare Integers use method compareTo().

Answer (score 1):

Use **int when you can and use Integer when you must**:

If the values can be null use `Integer` but you will have to use the methods `compareTo` and `Equals` to make comparison between then.

If your value can't be null, use`int`, that way you will have a more readable code with the classical operators `==`, `>=`, `<`, etc...

```
 // int primitive, easy to handle
 int a = 5;
 int b = 5;
 int c = null; // Compile error, can't have null primitive values
 if(a == b) // True
 if(a > b) // False
 if(a >= b) // True

 // Integer, more complicated:
 Integer A = new Integer(5);
 Integer B = new Integer(5);
 Integer c = null; // Work

 if(A == B) // False, they are not the same objects
 if(A.equals(B)) // True, same value

 if(A > B) // Compile error...
 if(A.compareTo(B)>0) // A > B, the int version is more readable
 if(A.compareTo(B)>=0) // A >= B, the int version is more readable
```

Answer (score 1):

For constants use `int`, as with constants you only need to be able to get their value. Everything else that comes with `Integer` is redundant in this case.

Where you need to pass integers as parameters, it's handy to use `Integer` as you get one more option of the parameter value being `null` (i.e. a case with an invalid parameter, or a legit no-value case).