# Conditionally ignore primitive typed fields with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

**Short Question**: Is there a way to optionally serialize a field depending on it's value in jackson? Is there a way to tell jackson, something like "if a certain integer field's value is 0, don't serialize it."

(skip the following if you get what I mean)

**Long Question** aka **Why would I want to do such a thing**:
Say I have a Spring MVC model class

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Foo {
    int a0;
    int a1;
    .
    .
    .
    int a99;
    String c;

    //getters and setters
}
```

For a new object of `Foo`, all `int` will get initialized to 0, The `String` to `null`. So if I serialize this object, I will only get `int`s in result, all set to 0, thanks to `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`.

In actual operation, say I have to reply with only **some** of the a1...a99, say a20 to a26, set to some meaningful value (to me it's something other than 0). It would be wise to send only those fields, right?

To achieve this, I can always change my `int` declarations to `Integer`. However, I have a lot of numerical computations over ints, and pondering over the net a bit and coming across links like [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998470/use-int-or-integer), I kinda want to stick to primitive types. Does there exist a solution satisfying both my needs?

Comment: if you are to choose Gson over jackson then you can do it using their exclusion strategy. refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations

Comment: I'm kinda too far to change the implementation, Thanks anyway : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [JSON Filters](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter). I think you will need to implement your own instance of `BeanPropertyFilter` though.

Comment: I was about halfway through JSON filters when I found one-line solution to my problem (find it posted).

Answer (score 2):

Okay. All I was missing was [`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html)

and a default constructor.

Also I shifted my Jackson dependencies from codehaus to [fasterxml](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

Comment: Still, as @Vidya suggests, I guess [JSON filters](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) is more flexible solution.